# How to store PBSPRO jobs in an array and check for job completion?

Tags: hpc, pbs, qsub

I'm trying to generate a system that allows me to check if multiple jobs have completed running on a cluster.
This bash code should work to wait until all PBS jobs have completed:

```
#create the array

ALLMYJOBS=()

# loop through scripts, submit them and store the job IDs in the array 

for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
ALLMYJOBS[${i}]=$(qsub script${i}.bash)
done    


JOBSR=true

# check if all jobs have completed:

while [ ${JOBSR} ];do

    JOBSR=false

    for m in "${ALLMYJOBS[@]}"
    do
        if qstat ${m} &> /dev/null; then
        JOBSR=true
        fi
    done
done
```

am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What is the result when you execute this?

Comment: it didn't leave the loop but I found the mistake

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was with the check itself:

while [ "${JOBSR}" = "true" ];do

This works apparently.

Answer (score 0):

The way your implemented will keep on polling the scheduler, which is undesirable for large cluster.

If I am to implement, I will use the job dependency, define another job depending on all your jobs, either check the output of the last job or use email notification.